# Still can't "Send As" after making the necessary changes into the mailbox permission using Exchange Management Console

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, outlook-2007

I still can't believe that I am still unable to "send as" from my Outlook using a particular mailbox, even though:

1. I was able to open up the Mailbox successfully as an additional mailbox in my Outlook
2. Grant my self "FULL ACCESS" and the "Send on Behalf"

Do I have to make this mailbox as "Shared mailbox" instead of normal user mailbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an Active Directory right. It's called "Send As" and is distinct from "Send on Behalf" rights. In the Management Console, you can right-click on the mailbox object and select "manage send as..." which is where it should be managed in Exchange 2007.
You can also set it from AD USers & Computers on the mailbox object, add an Advanced permission for the target user and grant "Send As". "Full Access" no longer grants "Send As" as of Exchange 2007, and possibly as of one of the later Exchange 2003 service-packs.

Comment: I can confirm that this also applies to at least the current SP level of Exchange 2003.

Comment: many thakns for your explanation mate, I was confused by "Send As" and "Send on the behalf of" and was just under the impression if I grant Full access then i can get everything.